# pandas boxplot: swap box placement for comparison

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

```
tmpdf.boxplot(['original','new'], by = 'by column', ax = ax, sym = '')
```

gets me a plot like this
[image]

I want to compare "original" with "new", how can I arrange to put the two "0" boxes in one panel and the two "1" boxes in another panel? And of course swap the labelling with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample dataset to demonstrate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# simulate some artificial data
# ==========================================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns=['original', 'new'] )
df['by column'] = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1])

# your original plot
ax = df.boxplot(['original', 'new'], by='by column', figsize=(12,6))
```

[image]

To get desired output, use `groupby` explicitly out of `boxplot`, so that we iterate over all subgroups, and plot a `boxplot` for each.

```
ax = df[['original', 'new']].groupby(df['by column']).boxplot(figsize=(12,6))
```

[image]